# Not able to click OK using sweet alert

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Code :

```
<script>
    swal('Your ORDER has been placed Successfully!!!');
    window.location="index.php";
</script>
```

Sweet alert works fine and redirects to the page as well but the problem is that alert does not allow to click OK and redirects to the page.

Any Solution??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your sample page will be redirected to index.php when sweetAlert closed. And It doesn't matter if you have clicked on OK or CANCEL buttons. You have to use sweetAlert's events to control "OK" click event.

Try this solution:

```
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "Some description",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, please redirect the page!",
    closeOnConfirm: false
}, function() {
  location.href="http://google.com"
});
```

[image]